# mb_substring does not remove comma(,) at the end of non-English string

Tags: php

I have the following code which as PHP documentation says needs '===' for condition checking.  Even after using the following code, the comma at the end of the string is not trimmed by the function. I have got mbstring installed in my system. **Note the comma at the end of input string**, I need to trim it smoothly. Am I missing something?

```
$string = "日本語版,";
if (mb_substr($string, -1, 'UTF-8') === ',')
{
        $length = mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');
    $string = mb_substr($string, 0, $length-1, 'UTF-8');
}
echo "Stirng without comma : ".$string;
```

The code still output as "日本語版," without removing comma, I thing it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script generates PHP Warning, because there is missing third argument

```
mb_substr($string, -1, 'UTF-8')
```

There should be

```
mb_substr($string, -1, 1, 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: does this mean the locating of last character, Jiri?

Comment: no Jiri, I had given both start and end index for substring. Just like this  **mb_substr($string, 0, $length-1, 'UTF-8')**

Comment: Calling mb_substr on second line (in if statement) is wrong. Function mb_substr expected as third argument length, not encoding. Read http://cz2.php.net/mb_substr

Comment: no, you could see that I have given everything string, start, end and encoding just as doucument said as well as in order. Still it doesn't work!

Comment: oh thank you. I am misssing the 'end' argument in if loop itself.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
$trimmed = rtrim($string, ",");
```

Comment: Yes, of course. It just trims the specified character from the right of the string

Comment: your suggestion is useful. Thanks for that. But why is our code in question not working?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, I have never used mb_substr.